# using sqlite3 and kivy

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('business_database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO business VALUES(self.nob_text_input.text, self.post_text_input.text, self.descrip_text_input.text )")

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I want to add records into my database using the TextInput in kivy hence the 'self.post_text_input.text' etc, but I get this error:

```
OperationalError: no such column: self.nob_text_input.text
```

I tried putting the columns next to table name in the query:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO business(column1, column2,column3) VALUES(self.nob_text_input.text....)
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you trying to use the values of the variables in `c.execute`? If so, you should use `"INSERT INTO business VALUES(%s, %s, %s)" % (self.nob_text_input.text, self.post_text_input.text, self.descrip_text_input.text)`. At the moment you're just putting the variable names in the string.

Comment: yeah that worked thanks but instead i used question marks as my placeholders instead

Comment: Ok. I've added an answer to make the solution more obvious to other people. Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into a more detailed answer.*

If you're trying to use the values of the variables (`self.nob_text_input.text` and friends) in the string, you need to embed those values in the string.

One way is to use a format string:

```py
"INSERT INTO business VALUES(%s, %s, %s)" % (self.nob_text_input.text, self.post_text_input.text, self.descrip_text_input.text)
```

And another is to just concatenate the strings:

```py
"INSERT INTO business VALUES(" + self.nob_text_input.text + ", " + self.post_text_input.text + ", " + self.descrip_text_input.text + ")"
```